# What is the relationship between the Windows Shell and File Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

The default Windows Shell (what linux users may know as the desktop environment) seems to share an executable with the Windows File Explorer (explorer.exe). They even share the same icon in the Task Manager. Why is this?

Comment: It is, in fact, the same executable. Why Microsoft did it this way, and how the program knows when to load as the DTE vs as a simple file manager, is not known to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Desktop is just a full-screen, borderless, background-customizable, specialized File Explorer window. Check out the similarity between the view settings for the Desktop:

```
PS keith> gp HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\bags\1\Desktop\


FFlags           : 1073742372
Mode             : 1
LogicalViewMode  : 3
IconSize         : 33
Sort             : {0, 0, 0, 0...}
GroupView        : 0
GroupByKey:FMTID : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
GroupByKey:PID   : 0
GroupByDirection : 1
IconLayouts      : {0, 0, 0, 0...}
IconNameVersion  : 1
PSPath           : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Sh
                   ell\bags\1\Desktop\
PSParentPath     : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Sh
                   ell\bags\1
PSChildName      : Desktop
PSDrive          : HKCU
PSProvider       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

with those of a saved view for a folder window:

```
PS keith> gp 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}\'


Rev              : 12
FFlags           : 1090519040
Vid              : {137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}
Mode             : 4
LogicalViewMode  : 1
IconSize         : 16
Sort             : {0, 0, 0, 0...}
ColInfo          : {0, 0, 0, 0...}
GroupView        : 0
GroupByKey:FMTID : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
GroupByKey:PID   : 0
GroupByDirection : 1
PSPath           : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settin
                   gs\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5
                   CC7}\
PSParentPath     : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local
                   Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Shell
PSChildName      : {5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}
PSDrive          : HKCU
PSProvider       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

And icons on the Desktop behave no differnetly from icons in a folder.

Answer (score 1):

The desktop *is* Explorer. It is one of the windows that Explorer
can display.

If you kill Explorer in Task Manager - then no desktop.

Comment: I know that killing explorer in the task manager kills the desktop, but why? If you launch explorer.exe after killing the desktop it doesn't reopen the desktop (the taskbar is still gone) it just opens file explorer... why?

Comment: Not true : Kill `explorer.exe` - no desktop, then use the menu `File > Run new task` to run `explorer.exe` - desktop is back. You must be calling Explorer in its File Manager interface.

Comment: huh. I guess you're right. Still doesn't explain why they're connected, tho. They seem like two completely different things

Comment: it did not answer the question of why these two different programs are under the same executable. It just repeats the question

Comment: They are not "under the same executable" - they are the same executable. If you don't agree that an executable can put up more than one window, there is nothing more to say.

Comment: the same executable, that's what I meant